# how to write nfc NTAG215 cards and read it without an app on iphone

Tags: nfc, core-nfc

I am interesting in writing an url to NTAG215 cards, so far I have download some apps for Ios tagwriter and NFC tools however once I try to read the card I have to open the app and read it, and my intention is to approach the phone and it will be able to pop up the window that let me open the link.

I have read and search quite a bit online about this but I am confused if this is something that needs to be develop using a sdk or its something the I have sort it out playing with the phone configuration.

any information will be much appreciated.
JL

Comment: Please describe in detail how you added data to the card, in theory if you have written the right type of NDEF record to the card then iOS will show a notification which when clicked will launch a web browser with the link.

Comment: thanks for response Andrew.
first I installed on my iphone the tagwriter app, then I grab the card "NTAG215" and I wrote an url to it. then when I try to read the card I couldn't read it approaching the phone.

instead I had to open the tagwriter app and click on read to be able to read it. 

that's what I don't want ... I want the phone to be able to recognize and pop up the windows once I approach the nfc card.

Comment: There are many different ways to write a URL to a card and iOS only supports some of them, hence needing details.

Answer (score 2):

So iOS does support some background processing of URL's in the correct form.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading

If you look at the NDEF spec https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-RTD_URI_1.0.pdf  and look to only support `URI Identifier Code` `3` & `4`  and possibly not `1` & `2`

And from Apple's doc's

> Note
> Background tag reading doesn’t support custom URL schemes. Use universal links instead.

Definitely not `URI Identifier Code` `0` (custom URL)

And NXP Tagwriter App seems to default to "custom URL", so try writing the URL using the `https://` or `http://` from the drop down menu.